# dyld[24496]: Symbol not found: _$s21DeveloperToolsSupport17UVPreviewRegistryCMn

Tags: xcode, ios17

In XCode 15 Beta, sample app runds fine on simulator but when i run it on my MacProo, It throw following error and

dyld[24496]: Symbol not found: _$s21DeveloperToolsSupport17UVPreviewRegistryCMn
Referenced from:  /Users/yhyq/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DeployTest-egtmabxxlwwfbwgbdfjebghqgrjp/Build/Products/Debug/DeployTest.app/Contents/MacOS/DeployTest
Expected in:      /System/Library/Frameworks/DeveloperToolsSupport.framework/Versions/A/DeveloperToolsSupport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error that your xcode and ios beta version not matching.

I had this exact issue recently when I updated my iphone to ios 17 beta 3 but didn't upgrade xcode 15 beta.

After updating to the latest xcode 15 beta 4, the problem gone now.

Comment: I still have this problem running Xcode 15 beta 4

Comment: @DavidBemerguy Did try to upgrade macos, xcode and ios device ALL to the most recent beta version. Also, try unpair ios device, and re-trust the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Easily **remove**

```
#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

from your code

Comment: as crazy as it is, worked for me, would you be able to say why?